# Tomcat7 shows error deploying my application saying 'MISSING TABLE:XXX'

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, ubuntu, tomcat7

I have 2 MySQL instances.One on my Windows machine and another on my Ubuntu instance.When i point my Ubuntu tomcat 'server.xml' to Windows machine it works as expected. I created MySQL server with the same database by reverse engineering on my Windows machine it says 'MISSING TABLE : XXXX'. When i try to access the MySQL Ubuntu instance remotely using MySQL Workbench with the same user i am able to access the table. Not sure where i went wrong.

Please let me know if you need anymore details to help me out.
Please Advice
Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Do you have your user set up with the correct permissions on the Ubuntu instance?

Comment: Yes i have.. If i haven't done that then i wont be able to connect to the database remotely too right? Which i am able to connect to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MySQL Official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), MySQL is case sensitive on Unix based platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In my entity class the name was in uppercase format. When i made it into lowercase it worked fine now. But still what i couldn't understand is when it worked fine with same scheme deployed in my windows machine why it didn't work on my Ubuntu MySQL. Why case sensitive in Ubuntu while its not in Windows.

Thanks for all your help